# How can I develop an Android app that utilizes Android Virtualisation Framework?

Tags: android

I'm interested to use AVF and experiment with the pVM (running on MicroDroid) for security. I tried to create a new app and import android.system.virtualmachine.* as shown in the example app but Android studio tells me that "virtualmachine" is unresolved.

I'm running Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738, built on September 1, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

I've set the targetAPI as 33.

I am unable to find any instructions on how to use AVF on Android Studio. Is it not supported? What can I do instead?

Thank you.